# jQuery Date Time picker that works well on iOS/Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, ios, datepicker

Is there a decent date time picker that works well on mobile devices? Everything I have found seems to be very clunky on a phone.

The other option is the four drop down selects for day, month, hour and minute. just seems like there must be a better solution out there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try [mobiscroll](http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&sugexp=gsis,i18n=true&cp=10&gs_id=z&xhr=t&q=mobiscroll&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&biw=1920&bih=1070&site=webhp&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=mobiscroll&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=ae5ee7b2fd60d6a0).

It works very well on android and iOS, and it comes with pre-defiend themes.
It can be used with scroll, or the "Android style" +/-.

Comment: +1 And it offers an API to change the order of the month/day/year controls, a thing that other controls often forget.

Comment: Looks nice, is it free? If not how much would it cost?

Comment: Not free, and Levi is one of the guys selling it.  Starts at $155 USD ?!

Comment: Apparently it's open source (MIT), available through https://github.com/acidb/mobiscroll .  Seems the pricing is primarily for support?

Comment: can anyone please confirm aboout the poricing model for this http://demo.mobiscroll.com/datetime/time

Comment: @streak visit the link Spoom mentioned. The license is MIT, meaning free to use.

Answer (score 2):

Check out my implementation of an Android-style datepicker for jQuery Mobile, called Mobi Pick

http://mobipick.sustainablepace.net/

Comment: This is only a datepicker, you can't pick the time.