# How can i add a time picker in my JQuery mobile app?

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, timepicker

I am developing an application in jquery mobile.
In that app i need to put a time picker.
How can i add a time picker to my app?.
if any one knows please help me....

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?  I googled "jquery time picker" and got lots of results.

Comment: But i want for JQuery mobile app for iphone?..
I have tried with <input type="time" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="" /> But it not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[mobiscroll](http://code.google.com/p/mobiscroll/)

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576281/jquery-date-time-picker-that-works-well-on-ios-android)

Comment: mobiscroll has now jQM Theme integration! http://blog.mobiscroll.com/jquery-mobile-theme-integration/